Type or namespace does not exist. ApplicationName.Models.Model
We're on Visual Studio Code, .NET 8 & Angular.
I changed the structure of my project and now I cannot use using directive in my app, it's driving me crazy.
Here is my structure: Structure
Expended it looks like that: expended structure
I know that namespace and using must match exactly.
I feel like I tried anything :

namespace    : BacApplication.Models.Model

global using : global using BacApplication.Models.Model;

namespace    : Models.Model

global using : global using Models.Model;


I tried to clean, restore and reload VS Code.
I deleted all caches of VS Code and reloaded with no pages open.
I checked that all of my versions matches together (I didn't add anything while changing structure so it is not may be the prob).
I have one project, so I do not need to target something.
My classes name are different than the namespace.
All of my namespaces in a folder are the same.
and others... I am surely missing something but I don't know what.
Thanks in advance for your help and sorry if the topic already exist, I did not find.

Hi Adrien, if it still not works for you, you can create a new sample without any sensitive information for me, I am willing to check it.

Here is my test result.

Structure

Need to modify


